# Python, Pandas, combining data from certain sheets of x number of excel documents

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a series of functions to extract data from certain sheets of x number of excel documents into one data frame.

What I have so far is:

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir(r'path')
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsm')
print(FileList)

for file in FileList: 
    df = extract_account(file, '2016')
    df = df.dropna()
    df_combined = pd.concat([df])
```

However, when I call `df_combined` it is returning only one df (I am expecting a minimum of 5 in my test). `extract_account(file_name, sheet_name)` is a function I have created which extracts the data I want for one file and it returns a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` object. My next step would then be to pass this function a list of years to extract from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is necessary create list of DataFrames and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together, also parameter `ignore_index=True` is for avoid duplicated index values in final `DataFrame`:

```
dfs = []
for file in FileList: 
    df = extract_account(file, '2016')
    df = df.dropna()
    dfs.append(df)
df_combined = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

If want also loop by years:

```
years = range(2016, 2020)

dfs = []
for file in FileList: 
    for year in years:
        df = extract_account(file, str(year))
        df = df.dropna()
        dfs.append(df)

df_combined = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Solution with list comprehension:

```
dfs = [extract_account(file, '2016').dropna() for file in FileList]
df_combined = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
dfs = [extract_account(file, str(y)).dropna() for file in FileList for y in years]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I want to add these on horizontally and your solution does this vertically?

Comment: @Maverick - so need `df_combined = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes thanks that does the job. Sorry not so proficient with Pandas yet, still learning!

Comment: @Maverick - You are welcome, btw, no necessary excuse :)